# .NET MAUI - Packaging to MSIX

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, maui

I am currently implementing continuous integration for my .NET MAUI application on Azure DevOps.

For Windows, I want to pack the Windows project into a .MSIX file.

I tried using the MSIX Build and Package extension from Azure DevOps, but it is not compatible with .csproj files from MAUI.

When I deploy the app from Visual Studio, it creates an Appx folder in bin/Release/net6.0-windows, containing assets, DLL's and AppxManifest.xml.

I can successfully create a .MSIX from this folder by using MakeAppx and Signtool from the Windows SDK.

But as I need this to be automated on Azure DevOps, I need to be able to create this Appx folder myself, using command-line only.

Does anyone have an idea, how I can approach this?